# How to bring the md-card contents accordingly when i select the item in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

1.I have 3 items namely, `ALL,Images and Videos`.

2. When i select all, i need both video and Images to display in 2 md-card.
3. When i select either Image or Video, i must get only that particular items to display.

[image]

In `All`, totally i have 5 data, 3 images and 2 videos. so i want 3 images data to be in image part and 2 in the video part, but here right now it is displaying all 5 data in both sections.
Right now for All, it is displaying like this.
So, now if i select, `Images` i want that to take only the images section and display in full page instead of getting 2 cards.

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px 20px 30px;">
        <md-card style="margin:10px -14px;float:left;padding-top:0px!important;padding-bottom:20px!important;" class="border-top-3px col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 taskDiv width49">
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size:20px;color: #55595c;">Images</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size:20px;color: #55595c;">Type</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size: 20px;color: #55595c;margin-right: 17%;margin-top: -8%;float: right;">Action</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content style="cursor: pointer;overflow-y:scroll;max-height:500px;">
                <md-card class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let media of images; let i = index ">
                  <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                    <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size:20px;">Image</h3>
                  </md-card-title>
                    <div class = "type-img" [hidden]= "selectedImage !='img'">
                      <img class="cat-img" src="{{media.image_path}}" style="width: 100px;margin: 10px 0px;float: right;" type='img' *ngIf="selectedImage=='img'|| selectedImage=='all'" />
                    </div>
                        <p class="inputimg" [ngClass]="{'video': selectedImage =='video'}" style="float: right;margin-right: 17%;margin-top:-4%">
                          <input type="file" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="inputfile" (change)="editGuideImage($event,media)" style='display: none;' />
                          <label *ngIf="media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Change</label>
                          <label *ngIf="!media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Add</label>
                          <label *ngIf="media._id" class="img_change" (click)="removeMedia(media)">Remove</label>
                        </p>
                </md-card>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
        <md-card style="margin:10px 0;float:right;padding-top:0px!important;padding-bottom:20px!important;" class="border-top-3px col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 taskDiv width49">
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing:0.6px;font-size: 20px;color: #55595c;">Videos</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size:20px;color: #55595c;">Type</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size: 20px;color: #55595c;margin-right: 17%;margin-top: -8%;float: right;">Action</h3>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content style="cursor: pointer;overflow-y:scroll;max-height:500px;">
                <md-card class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let media of images; let i = index ">
                  <md-card-title style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                    <h3 class="color-primary" style="margin: 2px 0px 2px 5px;letter-spacing: 0.6px;font-size:20px;">Video</h3>
                  </md-card-title>
                  <div class = "type-video" [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" >
                    <video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="{{media.image_path}}" type="video/mp4" *ngIf="selectedImage=='video'|| selectedImage=='all'" ></video>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "type-video" [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" > 
                    <span style="margin-left: 12%;">or </span> 
                    <input type="text" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" [(ngModel)]="media.editText" #editText pattern="/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ ]+$/" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;"></div> 
                  <div *ngIf="errorMsg" style="color:red">
                    {{errorMsg}}
                  </div>
                        <p class="inputimg" [ngClass]="{'video': selectedImage =='video'}" style="float: right;margin-right: 17%;margin-top:-4%">
                          <input type="file" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="inputfile" (change)="editGuideImage($event,media)" style='display: none;' />
                          <label *ngIf="media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Change</label>
                          <label *ngIf="!media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Add</label>
                          <label *ngIf="media._id" class="img_change" (click)="removeMedia(media)">Remove</label>
                        </p>
                </md-card>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ts:

```
this.guideImage = [
    {label:"All",value:"all"},
    { label:"Images",value: "img" },
    { label:"Video", value: "video" },
  ];
  this.selectedImage="all";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf with logic to switch between the cards.

Something simpler as example:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
        <mat-option value="1">All</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">Images</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="3">Videos</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
<mat-card *ngIf="selected==='1' || selected==='2'">Images card</mat-card>

<mat-card *ngIf="selected==='1' || selected==='3'">Videos card</mat-card>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhjqcs)**

Comment: It's mat- prefix as for latest version of angular material

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work? Do you use angular material latest version?